# exec-maven-plugin with npm install

Tags: maven, maven-plugin

I try to use exec-maven-plugin in my project.

Here is the code

```
            <plugin>
          <artifactId>exec-maven-plugin</artifactId>
          <groupId>org.codehaus.mojo</groupId>
          <version>1.6.0</version>
          <executions>
            <execution>
              <id>npm install</id>
              <goals>
                <goal>exec</goal>
              </goals>
              <phase>generate-resources</phase>
              <configuration>
                <executable>${node.directory}/${npm.executable}</executable>
                <arguments>
                  <argument>install</argument>
                </arguments>
                <workingDirectory>src/main/angular2/tourism</workingDirectory>
                <target>
                  <echo message="Npm install" />
                </target>
              </configuration>
            </execution>
          </executions>
        </plugin>
```

Here is my directory structure
[image]

And the mentioned error is

```
/Users/admin/Application-Marwen/workspace/Tourism/Tourism-Web/node/npm: line 34: node: command not found
```

Could you please help me

I use know frontend-maven-plugin

Here is the code

```
            <plugin>
            <groupId>com.github.eirslett</groupId>
            <artifactId>frontend-maven-plugin</artifactId>
            <version>1.6</version>
            <configuration>
                <workingDirectory>src/main/angular5/tourism</workingDirectory>
                <!-- where to install npm -->
                <installDirectory>src/main/angular5/tourisml</installDirectory>
            </configuration>                
            <executions>
                <execution>
                    <id>install node and npm</id>
                    <goals>
                        <goal>install-node-and-npm</goal>
                    </goals>
                    <phase>generate-resources</phase>
                    <configuration>
                        <nodeVersion>v8.11.3</nodeVersion>
                        <npmVersion>6.3.0</npmVersion>                      
                    </configuration>                        
                </execution>                  
                <execution>
                        <id>npm install</id>
                        <goals>
                            <goal>npm</goal>
                        </goals>
                        <!-- Optional configuration which provides for running any npm command -->
                        <configuration>
                            <arguments>install</arguments>
                            <workingDirectory>src/main/angular5/tourism</workingDirectory>
                        </configuration>
                 </execution>
                 <execution>
                     <id>prod</id>
                     <goals>
                       <goal>npm</goal>
                     </goals>
                     <configuration>
                       <arguments>run-script build</arguments>
                       <workingDirectory>src/main/angular5/tourism</workingDirectory>
                     </configuration>
                     <phase>generate-resources</phase>
                  </execution>                                                      
            </executions>
        </plugin>
        <plugin>
            <groupId>org.apache.maven.plugins</groupId>
            <artifactId>maven-assembly-plugin</artifactId>
            <configuration>
                <finalName>${project.artifactId}-${project.version}.zip</finalName>
                <appendAssemblyId>false</appendAssemblyId>
            </configuration>
            <executions>
                <execution>
                    <id>cfg-main-resources</id>
                    <goals>
                        <goal>single</goal>
                    </goals>
                    <phase>package</phase>
                    <configuration>
                        <descriptors>
                            <descriptor>${basedir}/src/main/angular5/tourism/assembly.xml</descriptor>
                        </descriptors>
                    </configuration>
                </execution>
            </executions>
        </plugin>
```

And the assembly.xml file

```
<assembly xmlns="http://maven.apache.org/plugins/maven-assembly-plugin/assembly/1.1.3"
      xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance"
      xsi:schemaLocation="http://maven.apache.org/plugins/maven-assembly-plugin/assembly/1.1.3 http://maven.apache.org/xsd/assembly-1.1.3.xsd">
<id>distribution</id>
<formats>
    <format>zip</format>
</formats>

<includeBaseDirectory>false</includeBaseDirectory>

<fileSets>
    <fileSet>
        <outputDirectory>statics</outputDirectory>
        <directory>dist</directory>
        <includes>
            <include>**/*</include>
        </includes>
    </fileSet>
</fileSets>
```

The objective is to prepare a zip file containing the compiled code to deploy it on server

Here is the obtained directory structure

[image]

1) I don't understand why the dist folder does not contain the compiled code (I wonder furthermore what it must contain exactly)
2) node and npm are installed in the directory tourisml/node, why
3) there is an error stating that

```
[ERROR] Failed to execute goal org.apache.maven.plugins:maven-assembly-plugin:2.4:single (cfg-main-resources) on project tourism-web: Failed to create assembly: Error creating assembly archive distribution: You must set at least one file. -> [Help 1]
org.apache.maven.lifecycle.LifecycleExecutionException: Failed to execute goal org.apache.maven.plugins:maven-assembly-plugin:2.4:single (cfg-main-resources) on project tourism-web: Failed to create assembly: Error creating assembly archive distribution: You must set at least one file.
```

Normally I should obtaine one zip file (${project.artifactId}-${project.version}.zip) and I suppose it failed because there is no files in. Is that correct ?

Comment: Hello norbjd, I added some more information in the first post

Answer (score 3):

Instead of using `exec-maven-plugin`, I suggest you to take a look at the [`frontend-maven-plugin`](https://github.com/eirslett/frontend-maven-plugin) to build your Node sources using `npm install`.

Using that plugin, you don't need to have `npm` or `node` installed on your machine : the plugin manages all by itself, so you should not encounter issues like `command not found`. Configuration like the following should work :

```xml
<plugin>
    <groupId>com.github.eirslett</groupId>
    <artifactId>frontend-maven-plugin</artifactId>
    <version>1.6</version>
    <configuration>
        <workingDirectory>src/main/angular5/tourism</workingDirectory>
        <!-- where to install npm -->
        <installDirectory>${project.build.directory}/install</installDirectory>
    </configuration>
    <executions>
        <execution>
            <id>install-node-and-npm</id>
            <goals>
                <goal>install-node-and-npm</goal>
            </goals>
            <configuration>
                <nodeVersion>v${node.version}</nodeVersion>
                <npmVersion>${npm.version}</npmVersion>
            </configuration>
        </execution>
        <execution>
            <id>npm-install</id>
            <goals>
                <goal>npm</goal>
            </goals>
            <configuration>
                <arguments>install</arguments>
            </configuration>
        </execution>
    </executions>
</plugin>
```

Comment: Hello, I tried to use frontend-maven-plugin, but I have the same issue(I obtained the same directory structure): [ERROR] Failed to execute goal com.github.eirslett:frontend-maven-plugin:1.6:npm (npm install) on project tourism-web: Failed to run task: 'npm install' failed. java.io.IOException: Cannot run program "/Users/admin/Application-Marwen/workspace/Tourism/Tourism-Web/src/main/angular5/tourism/node/node" (in directory "/Users/admin/Application-Marwen/workspace/Tourism/Tourism-Web/src/main/angular5/tourism"): error=2, No such file or directory -> [Help 1]

Comment: @flamant Just updated the answer with an example of configuration

Comment: What if you are working behind your companies proxy then frontend-maven-plugin wont be ideal as it will give proxy errors

Answer (score 0):

I have installed node and moved the installed folder under ${project.baseUri}/node/.

That error got resolved now and I can able to do npm install using below command in Command Prompt.

```
c:\main\prjt\apphost_prjt>mvn frontend:npm
```

Answer (score -2):

Finally, I used frontend-maven-plugin

Here is an extract of the pom.xml

```
        <plugin>
            <groupId>com.github.eirslett</groupId>
            <artifactId>frontend-maven-plugin</artifactId>
            <version>1.6</version>
            <configuration>
                <workingDirectory>src/main/angular5/tourism</workingDirectory>
                <!-- where to install npm -->
                <installDirectory>temp</installDirectory>
            </configuration>                
            <executions>
                <execution>
                    <id>install node and npm</id>
                    <goals>
                        <goal>install-node-and-npm</goal>
                    </goals>
                    <phase>generate-resources</phase>
                    <configuration>
                        <nodeVersion>v8.11.3</nodeVersion>
                        <npmVersion>6.3.0</npmVersion>                      
                    </configuration>                        
                </execution>
                <execution>
                        <id>npm install</id>
                        <goals>
                            <goal>npm</goal>
                        </goals>
                        <!-- Optional configuration which provides for running any npm command -->
                        <configuration>
                            <arguments>install</arguments> 
                        </configuration>
                 </execution>
                 <execution>
                     <id>prod</id>
                     <goals>
                       <goal>npm</goal>
                     </goals>
                     <configuration>
                       <arguments>run-script build</arguments>
                     </configuration>
                     <phase>generate-resources</phase>
                  </execution>                                                      
            </executions>
        </plugin>
```

Thank you for your answers

Comment: I suggest that you accept the answer above so that (1) other people are not confused when looking up the content and (2) the person who shared their knowledge here feels appreciated.