# How to set the node version that will be used as a part of mvn clean install in intelliJ idea?

Tags: node.js, maven, intellij-idea

I want to run `mvn clean install` using the built-in intelliJ Idea maven module.

One of the goals is this:

```
[INFO] --- exec-maven-plugin:1.6.0:exec (npm-install)
```

Which fails because the versions being used when the command executes are:

```
npm ERR! node v6.17.1
npm ERR! npm  v3.10.10
```

To be able to build the project I need to use node 16 and I can do it easily through the terminal (just write `nvm use 16` and run `mvn clean install` there), but I prefer running mvn commands through idea.

I have tried setting the node version through Idea settings in `Languages & Frameworks > Node.js` , but that didn't change the version being used for `mvn clean install`.

Is there any way to set the node version like the java version can be set in project settings?

Comment: Out of curiosity, why are you mixing maven and node?

Comment: Node is here because webpack is used for the frontend part of the service, but the rest is spring.

Comment: Why are you keeping such and ancient `node` version installed? Or any version other than the one you want to use for this installed?

Comment: I need it (not this ancient one, but different older ones) easily accessible to be able to build different services.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I found an answer [here](https://stackoverflow.com/a/51840354/22795059).

This [plugin](https://github.com/eirslett/frontend-maven-plugin) can be used to specify the node version when executing `mvn clean install`. Even though it is not exactly what I was looking for, being able to configure it through **Idea** by setting the version in the project settings or something like that, it got the job done.

Seems like Idea doesn't currently support what I wanted to do.